# TCL Extract URLs (and names) into lists

Tags: tcl

I have the following html data as follows:

```
<p><b>Posted Title 1/2</b></p>
            
            <ul>
                
                    <li><a href="displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=62434&documentDate=2020-12-15&documentNo=444">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;A  </a></li>
                    
                
                    <li><a href="displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=62435&documentDate=2000-12-16&documentNo=223049">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;B  </a></li>
                    
                
                    <li><a href="displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=6436&documentDate=2000-12-16&documentNo=223049">Additional  </a></li>
                    
                
            </ul>
```

...etc...

I need to extract the URL's and the names (Part A, Part B, Additional, etc.) into 2 seperate lists - eg utl_list and name_list, but can't seem to get my head around the extractions :( Manually stripping out the HTML code and then using a foreach loop after a \n split doesn't seem to be very efficient, since there could be many entries (not just the 3 examples above).

What's the best way to extract this data (regexp? lmap? anything else?), and how?

UPDATE: current code here: https://onecompiler.com/tcl/3yt4dabh8

```
# sample data - usually loaded from a htm file and stripped down to the following content
set code "\n                 <!-- start content -->\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n <h1>Notifications</h1>\n    <p>\n       Select from the available parts below.\n    </p>\n  \n\n    \n      \n          <p><b>Posted Title 1/2                </b></p>\n            \n          <ul>\n              \n                  <li><a href=\"displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=62434&documentDate=2020-12-15&documentNo=444\">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;A  </a></li>\n                  \n              \n                  <li><a href=\"displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=62435&documentDate=2000-12-16&documentNo=223049\">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;B  </a></li>\n               \n              \n                  <li><a href=\"displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=6436&documentDate=2000-12-16&documentNo=223049\">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;C  </a></li>\n                    \n              \n          </ul>\n     \n      \n  \n\n\n\n\n\n\n                <!-- end content -->\n\n"

# clean up the htm code and remove double spaces
regsub -all {&nbsp;} $code " " code
regsub -all {  } $code " " code

# extract each occurance of required criteria into a list
set listed [regexp -all -inline {<a href=\"(.*?)</a>} $code]

# loop through each element to get each name and url
foreach item $listed {
 # exclude filter criteria method (* sloppy - need to refine regexp command)
 if {![string match "*<a href=*" $item]} {
  # split url and name using seperator
   set new_items [split $item "\">"]
  # set clean list variable
   set clean_items {}
   # do not include empty elements and create a new list (* sloppy)
   foreach i $new_items {
     if {$i != ""} {lappend clean_items $i}
   }
   # set name (element 1) from list
   set tname [string trim [lindex $clean_items 1]]
   # set URL (element 0) from list
   set url [lindex $clean_items 0]
   # display the name and url for this entry
   puts "NAME = $tname"
   puts "URL  = $url"
   # create Name and URL lists
   # blah blah blah
 }
}
```

Comment: Use a XML parsing/xpath/etc. library like [tDOM](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tDOM) in HTML mode. If you provide a complete well-formed example document, I or someone else can come up with a proper answer...

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important to you, a pure Tcl package may be to be avoided.
Below a basic example with [Tclgumbo](https://sites.google.com/site/ray2501/tclgumbo?pli=1) ([Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) Tcl bindings) :

```
proc getTagNameA {node} {
    global utl_list name_list

    set type [gumbo::node_get_type $node]

    if {$type == $gumbo::GUMBO_NODE_ELEMENT} {
        if {[gumbo::element_get_tag_name $node] eq "a"} {
            # get text if present...
            set child [gumbo::element_get_children $node]
            if {$child ne "" && [gumbo::node_get_type $child] == $gumbo::GUMBO_NODE_TEXT} {
                lappend name_list [gumbo::text_get_text $child]
            }
            gumbo::element_get_attributes $node ; # get href attribute
            if {[info exists attribute(href)]} {
                lappend utl_list $attribute(href)
            }
        }
        # get child nodes...
        foreach child_node [gumbo::element_get_children $node] {
            getTagNameA $child_node
        }
    }
}

package require tclgumbo

set html "\n                 <!-- start content -->\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n <h1>Notifications</h1>\n    <p>\n       Select from the available parts below.\n    </p>\n  \n\n    \n      \n          <p><b>Posted Title 1/2                </b></p>\n            \n          <ul>\n              \n                  <li><a href=\"displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=62434&documentDate=2020-12-15&documentNo=444\">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;A  </a></li>\n                  \n              \n                  <li><a href=\"displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=62435&documentDate=2000-12-16&documentNo=223049\">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;B  </a></li>\n               \n              \n                  <li><a href=\"displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234&noticeId=6436&documentDate=2000-12-16&documentNo=223049\">Part&nbsp;&nbsp;C  </a></li>\n                    \n              \n          </ul>\n     \n      \n  \n\n\n\n\n\n\n                <!-- end content -->\n\n"
set utl_list {} ; set name_list {}
set output [gumbo::parse $html]
set root [gumbo::output_get_root $output]

getTagNameA $root
gumbo::destroy_output $output

puts "NAME = $name_list"
# NAME = {Part  A  } {Part  B  } {Part  C  }
puts "URL  = $utl_list"
# URL  = displaynotice.do?display=text&Id=1234...
```